# Rolling out new site features dynamically using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

To begin with: my question will probably spark a zillion opinions, and I am sure that what I am looking for can be implemented in a number of ways.

**Background:**

Sites like Google+ and Facebook push out new features to their users, sometimes a small number of users and sometimes they push new features to the entire public. Rolling out new site functionalities and features is probably what many websites do, including the mentioned ones here.

**In my case:**

I have a menu that is accessible by every user on the site, any time. This means it acts a little bit like the Start Menu in Windows in a very familiar way. Now, this menu of mine is drawn upon request by some PHP code. Currently I have a multidimensional array which holds all the menu items and links for navigation. The idea is that once in a while when a new feature is shipped, I’d add it to my multidimensional array (which will be generated by the database later), and the PHP code will render it in the menu as a new item with (NEW! highlight mark).

**My main question:**

Is the approach of using a database table a good way of enabling/disabling and rolling out new features to your users?

Example of what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Stick to DB. Will pay of in long-time.

Comment: *Currently I have a multidimensional array which holds all the menu items and links for navigation.* ... how deep is the nesting we're talking about here? Is a full navigational tree supported?

Comment: In which case, as mike.k's answer has it, you can cache the result set in a serialized text file (serialize is slightly quicker than json_encode, so if you're not using ajax). It's worth considering XML if you've got a deeply nested hierarchy as you'll generally pass the nav id in of the lowest branch on the tree (probably as a GET var). DOMDocument/XML allows you to easily fetch that specific node (getElementById) and work your way back up the tree to determine which nodes should be active without using messy recursive loops.

Comment: @CD001 Thanks for the tip dude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a near-static menu, you'll want to avoid constantly connecting to the database and running `SELECT` queries if a consistent result is expected.

The array which holds menu contents could be saved to another file using PHP's `serialize()` or `json_encode()` functions. The code you have to manipulate the menu table would call these to update the static file when changes are made. PHP components would load from these files to create the menu, instead of from the database.

Another method would be to put `json_encode()` content into one of your site's JavaScript files, include it into the page, and draw the menu using JavaScript. The browser will cache that file, and upon an update you could change the filename or increment a counter in it, and change the include line as well, perhaps `<script src='./menu_20150718.js'></script>` so that the browser loads updated content.

Comment: I can store menu items in Session and Cookie, and avoid connecting the the Database all the time it has to be rendered.

Comment: My main concern is, if the Database approach is good enough, for example, one can store items to be rendered, use a flag column to enable/disable items, use another column to store list order, and every time a new feature is being added, one adds that as an item to the table, the system picks it up in an array and renders.

Comment: Sessions can work for this, and just the database can also work. The question with both is scale. Each session stores data in a local file, so you have to check if there is enough space to support the number of people you expect. Each database connection and query consumes some resources, so based on expected load you should figure out what is ideal

Comment: Also consider an attack scenario, what if someone wants to fill your server with junk sessions to fill disk space?

Comment: I have a sessions table in my DB, there I store user Sessions.

Comment: Mike have other folks implemented it like this? It's bad that other folks on stackoverflow aren't responding to this question. I'd be glad to get my hands on more responses. Have you done something similar?

Comment: I've used various approaches. I have a database-heavy PHP application that places many variables which do not change often into a PHP file that loads as an include. I've also stored user preferences in the database to then put into a session, so that everything can take on the same state at the next login and then the session takes over. I think a lot of developers use frameworks so much now that they perhaps don't give things like this consideration.

Comment: I have a framework of my own, except, it isn't MVC-based, it is very different. I have a session manager, I have extended the PHP's PDO, and I have a lot of extras in my /lib/ folder including Template Processor all written from the ground up. But on the general, do you think it is a wise approach to store menu items (which also represent features & tools) in the database, load them into an ordered array and store the array in session and cookie.

Comment: Sounds like you have a good process in place

Comment: DB based approach would be more effective in this case. Imagine retrieving data of users who have clicked the new feature or how many features are viewed. It could be a struggle using file based approach (well, not going into details how DB stores data). Also, if using MySQL there are some caching mechanisms implemented in the core. And if you choose to not use DB, why would not simply write the menu in PHP file? Using the methods you provided is additional and unnecessary overhead. Pure PHP arrays would be just fine. The same goes for JS - you are already making a request - make the menu here

Comment: @sitilge I cannot agree about the JS part, especially, since I need to have support for it even when the JS support is Disabled through client browser.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure there is any modern website that can function without JS being enabled at the client side

Comment: @mike.k - this is very very TRUE indeed man. :D

Answer (score 1):

Think you may be right this question is likely to spark different opinions ;-). IMO the key part of your question is in bold below:

> Sites like Google+ and Facebook push out new features to their users,
>   **sometimes a small number of users** and sometimes they push new features to the entire public.

Does the database have a `User` table or similar holding all known users? If so, it would make sense to provide the flexibility of choosing to roll out features to selected users, perhaps manually selected or perhaps based on criteria such as their role, geographic location, profile etc. In this case, it would make most sense to utilise the relational features of the database, e.g. create a `Feature` table and a many-to-many relationship with `User` via an intermediary such as `UserFeature`(*). This would avoid future maintenance headaches associated with the dynamic user data.

(*) *or choose your own preferred granularity*

Comment: Steve Chambers, I am NOT utilizing the relational database connection, i.e. foreign keys etc. Especially, since this can get messy in the long-run. I utilize the PHP itself, to keep track of that by having a user_id somewhere in a table etc.